# POST to IdentityServer Login endpoint works in Fiddler; not in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, identityserver4, fiddler

I have a POST that is working in Fiddler via Composer. It returns a 200. I'm trying to get it working in JMeter so I can use it as part of a load test. I've spent several hours trying to confirm that everything is the same between the two requests and as far as I could tell it was. At one point I took the Fiddler request, exported it to a .har file and used BlazeMeter's converter tool to create a new .JMX file from it. I ran that in JMeter and it, too, failed. I've also extracted the Fiddler session (that worked and returned a 200) to cURL and then used JMeter's Import from cURL Tool directly. Same result.

The failures are always the same - Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-ServerName: MYSERVER
Date: Sat, 14 Nov 2020 21:13:35 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
```

Cookies are being tracked and sent, including .AspNetCore.Antiforgery token cookie.

Headers are being sent correctly.

__RequestVerificationToken is being passed properly.

There is nothing in the server logs from these requests - it's as if they don't exist. If I modify the request to break in some manner, such as an invalid Content-Type header, I can get an error in the logs. But otherwise when these Bad Requests occur, there is nothing in the server logs.

Are there any known issues with JMeter and IIS or ASP.NET Core that would cause requests sent from it to be treated differently and rejected? Literally the same request, when converted to .JMX is failing while it works from Fiddler.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to [ASP.NET](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet) applications load testing you won't be able to just replay the recorded script as you will need to perform the correlation of at least this [`__RequestVerificationToken`  value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-5.0), you'll need to extract it from the previous response using a suitable JMeter's Post-Processor, convert it into a JMeter Variable and use this dynamic value instead of the recorded hard-coded one

Nore inforation: [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter)

Don't forget to add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan

Comment: That's being done. And in this case, even when it's not, and I just replay the exact same POST (without a GET to get a new token) in Fiddler, I get a 200 every time.